# How to do optimal query Google App Engine Data store about overlapping time ranges

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have some **reservation with start and end** (reference to resource is remove to make example more clear):

```
class Reservation(db.Model):
  fromHour = db.DateTimeProperty()
  toHour = db.DateTimeProperty()
  fromToRange = db.ComputedProperty(lambda x: [x.fromHour, x.toHour])
```

And want to **add another reservation** with check if it not **overlaps** previous one - how to express such query in Google App Engine.

**1st** I try this query with **list property** but **double inequality filters** not works. It should do two matches from1 < to2 and from1 >= from2 and one results - whatever it could be costly if there will be more data.

```
fromHour = datetime.datetime(2012, 04, 18, 0, 0, 0)
toHour = datetime.datetime(2012, 04, 18, 2, 0, 0)

reservation = Reservation(fromHour = fromHour, toHour = toHour, colors = ['white', 'black'])
reservation.put()

self.response.out.write('<p>Both %s</p>' % fromHour)    
self.response.out.write('<ol>')    
for reservation in Reservation.all()\
  .filter('fromToRange >', fromHour)\
  .filter('fromToRange <=', fromHour):
  self.response.out.write('<li>%s</li>' % (reservation.fromToRange))
self.response.out.write('</ol>')
```

I found **another solution** that I could use additional property containing days (this will be list of days in range per reservation) than I could hit days need to be checked  to narrow scan of data and check every record if not overlapping new reservation.

Please help and provide some answer how to do optimal query to detect overlapping reservations - maybe there is quick 3rd solution for time ranges queries in Google App Engine or is not supported.

Comment: It's not an answer, but this sort of query is inefficient in _any_ database without spatial/multidimensional indexing. Regular indexes just don't work for this sort of query.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, multiple inequality filters limitation on queries makes some things very hard/suboptimal to do. For instance geo searching.

I'd go with a solution that you proposed: quantizing the property value and saving all quantized values in the list property, e.g. saving all days that duration spans inclusively into a list property. The tricky part is to choose the right quantizing level: days, hours, etc..

Personally I'd start with universal time scale: Unix time (epoch), then round it to second and then decimally quantize it. For example cut three zeros from it (1000 second quantizer, spans ~ 16 mins) and save all quantized values from start time to end time in a list.

If the quantizer is too fine, then use bigger one: 10000 sec.

Then you can simply query on the list property with an equality filter and additionally filter results in memory to account for exact duration start and end time.

Comment: Yes it is very similar to geo search and is possible to use quantization/time hashes.